# apply a function on columns with specific names

Tags: r

I am new in R.
I have hundreds of data frames like this

```
ID  NAME    Ratio_A Ratio_B Ratio_C Ratio_D
AA  ABCD    0.09    0.67    0.10    0.14
AB  ABCE    0.04    0.85    0.04    0.06
AC  ABCG    0.43    0.21    0.54    0.14
AD  ABCF    0.16    0.62    0.25    0.97
AF  ABCJ    0.59    0.37    0.66    0.07
```

This is just an example. The number and  names of the `Ratio_` columns are different between data frames, but all of them start with `Ratio_`. I want to apply a function (for example, `log(x)`), to the `Ratio_` columns without specify the column number or the whole name.

I know how to do it df by df, for the one in the example:

```
A <- function(x) log(x)
df_log<-data.frame(df[1:2], lapply(df[3:6], A))
```

but I have a lot of them, and as I said the number of columns is different in each.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: How are the input data frames organized? Are they in a list? How do you want your output? In a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the datasets in a `list` and then loop over the `list` elements

```
lapply(lst, function(x) {i1 <- grep("^Ratio_", names(x));
                         x[i1] <- lapply(x[i1], A)
                          x})
```

NOTE: No external packages are used.

#### data

```
lst <- mget(paste0("df", 1:100))
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem is very easily dealt with using the [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) package. For example,

```
df <- read.table(text = 'ID  NAME    Ratio_A Ratio_B Ratio_C Ratio_D
                         AA  ABCD    0.09    0.67    0.10    0.14
                         AB  ABCE    0.04    0.85    0.04    0.06
                         AC  ABCG    0.43    0.21    0.54    0.14
                         AD  ABCF    0.16    0.62    0.25    0.97
                         AF  ABCJ    0.59    0.37    0.66    0.07', 
                 header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)

df_transformed <- mutate_each(df, funs(log(.)), starts_with("Ratio_"))

df_transformed
# > df_transformed
# ID NAME    Ratio_A    Ratio_B    Ratio_C     Ratio_D
# 1 AA ABCD -2.4079456 -0.4004776 -2.3025851 -1.96611286
# 2 AB ABCE -3.2188758 -0.1625189 -3.2188758 -2.81341072
# 3 AC ABCG -0.8439701 -1.5606477 -0.6161861 -1.96611286
# 4 AD ABCF -1.8325815 -0.4780358 -1.3862944 -0.03045921
# 5 AF ABCJ -0.5276327 -0.9942523 -0.4155154 -2.65926004
```

Comment: Good to know this using `dplyr` package. Thanks